# How to prevent Excel Cell format from changing

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi, abstractexcelview

I am currently using [AbstractExcelView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/document/AbstractExcelView.html) to export some data into excel file.

The data format of all the columns in the excel file is "General".
[image]

However when I enter the cell column, it changes format to date

[image]

Is there any  AbstractExcelView API or way to set the column data type so that it cant be changed ?

Comment: Just checking, you do realize that if you enter that date and excel is set to general, or rather you switch it back to general your date, you will see it in the format excel stores dates?  If you do not which to have the date changed to the excel format of a date, you could try entering it as text by prefacing the date entry with '

Comment: Can you add some code to show what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

After much research, I have found the answer to my questions

Create the two main objects : DateFormat & CellStyle which will be used to format the cell

```
  // To set these columns to text format
    final DataFormat fmt = workbook.createDataFormat();
    final CellStyle textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
```

Set the style and format of the cell

> ```
>     textStyle.setDataFormat(fmt.getFormat("@"));
>     excelSheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, textStyle);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest that you :

1. change the format of the cells in the column from *General* to *Text*
2. import the data
3. change the format of the cells in the column back to *General*